# $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{x}−\frac{2}{e^{2x}−1}$ doesn't get solved as expected

Tags: calculus, limits

A question says $f:\Bbb R\setminus\{0\} \to \Bbb R$, $f(x)=\dfrac{1}{x}−\dfrac{2}{e^{2x}−1}$. The limit as the function approaches $x=0$ is logically $0$, as in;

$\lim \limits_{x \to 0}\dfrac{e^{2x}-1}{2x} = 1$ This function then becomes $\dfrac{1}{x}−\dfrac{2}{2x} =0$

But when I graphed it online, the function approached $1$.

Comment: You should find the approximation of $e^{2x}-1$ to at least order $x^{-2}$. When you use only the first-order approximation, the two parts may cancel each other out, which gives you $0$ mistakenly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did an approximation error. When $x\to0$ it is $\frac{2}{e^{2x}-1}=\frac{2}{1+2x+\frac{1}{2}(2x)^2+\text{o}(x^2)-1}=\frac{1}{x+x^2+\text{o}(x^2)}$, so
$$\frac{1}{x}-\frac{2}{e^{2x}-1}=\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{x+x^2+\text{o}(x^2)}=\frac{1}{x}\left(1-\frac{1}{1+x+\text{o}(x)}\right)$$
Using the fact that $\frac{1}{1+\varepsilon}=1-\varepsilon+\text{o}(\varepsilon)$ when $\varepsilon \to 0$, you have
$$\frac{1}{x}\left(1-\frac{1}{1+x+\text{o}(x)}\right)=\frac{1}{x}\left(1-1+x+\text{o}(x)\right)=1+\text{o}(1) \to 1 \ \text{when} \ x \to 0$$

Comment: But isn't $\lim \limits_{x \to 0}\frac{e^x-1}{x}= 1$ derived from L'Hôpital's rule and not from an expansion? How would there be any need of approximation?

Comment: Your mistake is that you're taking the limit of the function by pieces, when you have to take the limit of the whole function together. You can't "substitute" the limit result of $\frac{2}{e^{2x}-1}$ and leave the rest of the function $\frac{1}{x}$ intact, because that limit result is obtained when $x \to 0$ but when you let $x \to 0$ you can't ignore the fact that $\frac{1}{x}$ is going to its limit too.
However, if you write the function as $\frac{e^{2x}-1-2x}{x(e^{2x}-1)}$, using two times L'Hôpital's rule you'll get the correct result $1$.

Comment: This is what I needed, thanks. Can you add it to the answer?

Answer (score 1):

Rearranging the equation and applying L'Hopital rule twice gives the correct answer.
$$\lim \limits_{x \to 0} \frac{e^{2x}-1-2x}{x(e^{2x}-1)}$$
$$=\lim \limits_{x \to 0} \frac{2e^{2x}-2}{(e^{2x}-1)+2xe^{2x}}$$
$$=\lim \limits_{x \to 0} \frac{4e^{2x}}{2e^{2x} + 2e^{2x} + 4xe^{2x}}$$
$$=1$$